# HTML Script of type text/html - templates

Tags: jquery, if-statement, syntax, template-engine

I came across this code in a website I am maintaining:

```
<script type="text/html" id="searchList">
<li class="listing ${ $data.EvenOdd }">
  {{if $data.DisplaySaleTag }}
{<span class="price">${ $data.Price }</span>}
  {{/if}}
</li>
</script>
```

I read on another post that a script tag of `type="text/html"` is not recognized by browsers and so they are ignored, and that it is probably used by a javascript templating engine. I pretty sure it is using [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/) template API (correct if I'm wrong).

Anyway, I need to modify this code to be (say C# syntax) `if(!$data.DisplaySaleTag)`, but `{{if !$data.DisplaySaleTag }}` is not working. How can I code a `not` into this `if` statement? Is there any documentation for this template API code? It seems so foreign..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to use `else`:

```
{{if condition}}

{{else}}

{{/if}}
```

http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-else/

Comment: I see. So, other than data-binding, this template API doesn't seem to go much beyond `if` statements, am I correct?

Comment: @Shredder - For the most part you are correct. There are some for loops, basic if/else. I am sure there are some tricks, I have not used it much, you might try knockout.js, it is pretty cool.